# How to do HTTPS connection with OkHttp

Tags: android, https, okhttp

### Summary:

---

I am currently developing an Android-App and a Server. I want the App to connect to the server via HTTPS and send and receive data from it. When I wanted to test the App for the first time on my hardware device, I got an error, telling me that I have to use HTTPS. That was when I started to implement HTTPS. I created the self-signed certification file, added that to the App and my server and configured both sides. The server works fine due to tests with **postman** and **web browser** tests. Only the Android-App doesn't work properly, but it worked after implementing my own **HostnameVerifier()**...

Well, I had big struggle to get that all to work, especially for my App. It was when I came across the **HostnameVerifier()** part mentioned everywhere that made the App connect successfully to my HTTP-server! But everyone also mentions how dangerous it is to **implement an own HostnameVerifier**.

**This is what I am using for an HTTPS connection via Android:**

- OkHttp for data transfer via HTTP/HTTPS
- A self signed certification (a ".crt"-file), created with OpenSSL

**Necessary things that I implemented due to the informations from the web:**

- Created the "res/xml/network_security_config.xml" file
- Added the cert-file into "res/raw/api.crt"
- Added the reference to the "network_security_config.xml" in "AndroidManifest.xml"

### Question/s:

---

That is why I am asking you fellas for help. I want to know how to implement a correct way to connect to an HTTPS-Server with the **OkHttp-Library**, since my App only works with the following code-snippet...

```java
this.builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                Log.i("INFO", "hostnameVerifier - string: "+s);
                    return true;
                }
        });
}
```

...which I want to go apart from since everyone is saying not to do that.

### Code and more:

---

**This is my self created, simple class that manages the neede connections and configurations via OkHttp:**

Please note the **"this.builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier()"**-part that has **"return true;"** in it. Currently it only works with that beeing **true** which I want to go apart from.

```java
public class OkHttpRequest {
    
    ...
    
    public OkHttpRequest(Context context) throws CertificateException, KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException{
        this.context = context;
        this.cookieManager = new CookieManager();
        this.cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
        this.cookieJar = new JavaNetCookieJar(this.cookieManager);
        this.client = new OkHttpClient();
        this.builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        this.builder.cookieJar(this.cookieJar);
        this.cf = null;
        this.cert = null;

        try{
            this.cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance(this.CERT_STANDART);
            this.cert = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.api);
            this.ca = this.cf.generateCertificate(this.cert);

            // creating a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
            String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", this.ca);

            // creating a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(keyStore);

            TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();

            if (trustManagers.length != 1 || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof X509TrustManager)) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:" + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
            }

            X509TrustManager trustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { trustManager }, null);
            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

            this.builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager);
            this.builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                    Log.i("INFO", "hostnameVerifier - string: "+s);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }finally{
            cert.close();
        }
    }

    public void DoPost(String url, Intent intent){

        this.builder.addInterceptor(CreateInterceptor());
        OkHttpClient client = builder.build();

        RequestBody postBody = RequestBody.create(JSON, "");
        Request post = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(postBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(post).enqueue(new Callback() {
            ...
        });
    }

    ...
}
```

**This is the "res/xml/network_security_config.xml"-File:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/api"/>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>

    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">https://[THIS_IS_A_LOCAL_IP_WITHOUT_PORT]/</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/api"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

**The "AndroidManifest.xml"-File:**

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="...">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        ...
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Your problem stems from `THIS_IS_A_LOCAL_IP_WITHOUT_PORT`. SSL certificates are meant to be issued to domain names, not IP addresses. As such, not everything is going to be happy with your certificate, and that includes Android.

If this is your own private project, and your app will only ever be used with this one device and never distributed, you're welcome to keep that `HostnameVerifier` if you want. If, however, you intend to distribute this app, you are going to need to either write a better `HostnameVerifier` or get rid of the `HostnameVerifier`.

Comment: That makes sense. But still I am asking myself if the rest of my logic is clean or not. Also I would like to know how to use `HostnameVerifier` for the future.

Comment: The simplest solution, by far, is to not use a self-signed certificate based off of an IP address. Get a domain name and use Let's Encrypt for a free real SSL certificate for that domain name. You can point that domain name to a private IP address if you wish. If you want to ship an app with a `HostnameVerifier`, that `HostnameVerifier` needs to do *something* to verify the hostname: confirming that the hostname of the SSL certificate matches expectations. Blindly returning `true` does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to use OkHttp classes to configure the trusted certificates

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CustomTrust.java

```
    // This implementation just embeds the PEM files in Java strings; most applications will
    // instead read this from a resource file that gets bundled with the application.

    HandshakeCertificates certificates = new HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
        .addTrustedCertificate(letsEncryptCertificateAuthority)
        .addTrustedCertificate(entrustRootCertificateAuthority)
        .addTrustedCertificate(comodoRsaCertificationAuthority)
        // Uncomment if standard certificates are also required.
        //.addPlatformTrustedCertificates()
        .build();

    client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .sslSocketFactory(certificates.sslSocketFactory(), certificates.trustManager())
            .build();
```